# add coastline on raster plot in R

Tags: ggplot2, mapping, raster, distribution, netcdf

I want to add a border and land portion around the distribution map of the Black Sea that I plotted with Raster. Below is my code and map:

```
library(ncdf4) #  netcdf manipulation
library(raster) #  raster manipulation
library(rgdal) 


nc_data0 <- nc_open("Biomass_Simu0.nc")
biomass0 <- ncvar_get(nc_data0, "Biomass")

nc_data1 <- nc_open("Biomass_Simu1.nc")
biomass1 <- ncvar_get(nc_data1, "Biomass")
 
lon <- ncvar_get(nc_data0, "longitude") #same dim with nc_data1
nlon <- dim(lon)
lat <- ncvar_get(nc_data0, "latitude", verbose = F) #same dim with nc_data1
nlat <- dim(lat)

Biomass_avg <- (biomass0 + biomass1 )/2

a <- apply(Biomass_avg, c(1,2,3), mean)

r1 <- raster(t(a[ , , 1]), xmn=min(lon), xmx=max(lon), ymn=min(lat), ymx=max(lat), crs=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs+ towgs84=0,0,0"))
r1 <- flip(r1, direction='y')
plot(r1)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mx6Vz.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest solution is to get a shapefile of the coast and plot it over your raster. You can achieve so with `giscoR::gisco_get_coastallines()`:

```r
library(raster) #  raster manipulation

# Just ignore this part, I am mocking your data
blacksea <- raster::raster(
  xmn = 26, xmx = 42, ymn = 40,
  ymx = 47
)



r1 <- elevatr::get_elev_raster(blacksea, z = 6, clip = "bbox")
r1[r1 > 0] <- NA
# End mock data

plot(r1, col = hcl.colors(10, "Blues"))
```

[image]

```r
# Now get coastalines
library(giscoR)
coast <- gisco_get_coastallines(resolution = 3)


plot(coast$geometry, add = TRUE, col = "grey")
```

[image]

## If you want to use ggplot2

Since the question is tagged under **ggplot2**, you can also achieve so by:

- Using the package **terra** instead or **raster**. Note that **terra** is the replacement of **raster**, created by the same developer but faster and easier. Overall I would recommed switch to **terra** if possible for any raster-involving data treatment.
- Using **tidyterra** for plotting.

Following the example:

```r
library(terra)
library(tidyterra)
library(ggplot2)

# Convert from raster to terra is as simply as terra::rast()
r1_terra <- rast(r1)

ggplot() +
  geom_spatraster(data = r1_terra) +
  geom_sf(data = coast, fill = "grey") +
  scale_fill_hypso_c(palette = "etopo1_bathy") +
  coord_sf(
    xlim = c(27, 42),
    ylim = c(40, 47)
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your approach to reading netcdf files seem excessively complicated. You should be able to use `raster::brick` or better, as I show below, `terra::rast`.

```
library(terra)
biomass0 <- rast("Biomass_Simu0.nc", "Biomass")
biomass1 <- rast("Biomass_Simu1.nc", "Biomass")
Biomass_avg <- mean(biomass0, biomass1)
# ?
a <- mean(Biomass_avg)
```

Get coastlines

```
library(geodata)
w <- world(path=".")
coast <- aggregate(w)
```

Plot

```
plot(a) 
lines(coast)
```